# iText 7.1.0 flattening signature field with appearance stretched

Tags: itext, pdfbox, itext7

I have a PDF (https://github.com/giacgbj/stackOverflow/blob/master/xxx.pdf), somehow digitally signed by a third party, whose signature has an appearance

[image: original]

When I flatten the PDF (https://github.com/giacgbj/stackOverflow/blob/master/xxxFlattened.pdf) using the following code (iText 7.1.0)

```
try (PdfWriter output = new PdfWriter("output.pdf");
            PdfDocument input = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("input.pdf"), output)) {
   PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(input, true).flattenFields();
}
```

the appearance of the signature is stretched like this:

[image: stretched]

Flattening the same PDF using PDFBox or command line arguments like GhostScript or convert (imagemagick) or pdf2ps/ps2pdf works.

What's the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the signature annotation has this **Rect** value:

```
[35.0 115.0 215.0 155.0]
```

which is a rectangle with its lower left at (35,115) and the upper left at (215,155), i.e. a rectangle 180 wide and 40 high.

Its appearance, though, has this **BBox** value:

```
[100.0 50.0 0.0 0.0]
```

which is a rectangle 100 units wide and 50 high. (Strictly speaking this is not completely valid: generally in PDFs rectangles are *written  as  an  array  of  four  numbers  giving  the coordinates  of  a pair  of  diagonally opposite  corners.* For **BBox** values, though, the order is fixed: *An array of four numbers giving the left, bottom, right, and top coordinates, respectively.* But the problem discussed here also turns up if the correct order is used.)

According to the PDF specification the appearance will be stretched to match the annotation rectangle.

During flattening, though, the former signature appearance is added to the page using a transformation matrix of:

```
1 0 0 1 35 115
```

which correctly positions its lower left at (35,115) but maps the rectangle using the identity matrix; thus, it incorrectly is not stretched to a size of 180x40 but remains a 100x50 which is the stretch (actually the missing stretch!) you observe.

In short, you appear to have found a bug in iText, a missing transformation...

Comment: The same problem is documented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47755629/1729265).

Comment: So the bug exists in all iText Version (1.X-7.X).

Comment: It's added to the internal bug tracker at iText Software.

Comment: I suspect that the weird BBox comes from a longtime bug in PDFBox. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4011

Comment: @Tilman but your remark and link made me realise that **BBox** coordinates are special. I added a hint to that effect to the answer.

Comment: So how should the correct bounding box look like? 0 0 100 50?

Comment: So, even if the original PDF will be produced using the next version of PDFBox, flattening it with the current version of iText will still produce the bug?

@AmedeeVanGasse is there a way to follow the ticket on iText?

Comment: @Jhack if you are a customer with a support contract then you have a login for our Jira and I can give you access to the ticket. If you are not a customer but an open source user, then sorry, no.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Can you tell the jira ticket ID? Some clients are customers so I can relay...

Comment: Please send an email to support@itextpdf.com from an email address of a registered user and we'll take care of it.

Comment: @Jhack and for everybody how wants to know: The bug id is DEVSIX-1741.   (@)AmedeeVanGasse You obviously don't :-( We contacted iText support a long time ago, opened a support request but nothing happend. Tomorrow is the sad 1/2 year birthday of this bug and no sign of a fix.

Comment: @Lonzak Quite a coincidence, yesterday evening there was a commit related to that issue with a comment "Scale flattened form fields appearance properly" followed by commits related to tests of this. ;)

Comment: @mkl Yeah I just saw it - but 1/2year fixing time is still way to long. I should have just fixed it by myself but thought what's commercial support for?!